# Use of undeclared Identifier in UITestFieldTest in cocos2d-x ios

Tags: c++, ios, xcode6, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am pretty much new to cocos2d-x.I am developing an authentication screen where i am using TextField.I am getting an error in UITextFieldTest as use of Undeclared Identifier, where i would be adding it to the eventListener.Am i missing any header files.I have attached a code below.

```
    TextField* userName = TextField::create("User Name","fonts/Marker Felt.ttf",20);
    userName ->ignoreContentAdaptWithSize(false);
    userName->setPosition(Point((visibleSize.width/2)+origin.x,(visibleSize.height/2)+origin.y+50));
    userName ->setContentSize(Size(240, 160));
    userName ->setTextHorizontalAlignment(TextHAlignment::CENTER);
    userName ->setTextVerticalAlignment(TextVAlignment::CENTER);
   userName->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(UITextFieldTest::textFieldEvent, this));
    this->addChild(userName);
```

Comment: And what is the undeclared identifier...?

Comment: Where do you define the `UITextFieldTest` class?

Comment: @melak47 UITextFieldTest

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I just refered the cocos2d-x Documentation..Is that a call back specifying to the class UITextFieldTest? ..Doc link..http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this may be a case of misread example, or rather that the example was too short - it seems that the example didn't show that the code was inside a class called `UITextFieldTest`.

To make it work, let's assume that your class is called `MyClass`, and you would want to handle the text field events in a method called `userNameTextFieldHandler`, you'd need something like this :

```
userName->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(MyClass::userNameTextFieldHandler, this));
```

And somewhere in your `MyClass` class :

```
void userNameTextFieldHandler(TextField *sender, TextField::EventType type) {

    // your implementation goes here

}
```

Comment: I created a class Myclass and included the header in .cpp file from where i am making a call.But i am still getting error in MyClass in addEventListener.Am i missing something.?

Comment: There is no need to create a new class, it would actually require more work. Just replace `MyClass` in my example with the name of the class in which you have the code you posted in the original question.

Comment: I replaced it.I am getting an error "No viable conversion from _bind<void Helloworld" cocos::UI::textField

Comment: Is this the whole error? It looks like it got cut while copy-pasteing.

Comment: I have fixed the issue.My bad...Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

import in header

```
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"
```

and write your ccp class

```
   ui::TextField* userName = ui::TextField::create("User Name","fonts/Marker Felt.ttf",20);
            userName ->ignoreContentAdaptWithSize(false);
            userName->setPosition(Point((visibleSize.width/2)+origin.x,(visibleSize.height/2)+origin.y+50));
            userName ->setContentSize(Size(240, 160));
            userName ->setTextHorizontalAlignment(ui::TextHAlignment::CENTER);
            userName ->setTextVerticalAlignment(ui::TextVAlignment::CENTER);
           userName->addEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(ui::UITextFieldTest::textFieldEvent, this));
            this->addChild(userName);
```